Nuxt3 allowing all HTTP methods for pages/ directory routes
By default nuxt3 is allowing all http methods for all routes in pages/ directory.
curl 'http://localhost:3000/route1'
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/route1'
curl --request DELETE 'http://localhost:3000/route1'
for pages/route1.vue.
All 3 returning same data. Ideally I expect only GET to work here.
How can I disable other http methods using something in nuxt config?
(I can do this via Nginx but mainly checking for nuxt settings)
Thanks in advance.

Solution is use nuxt-security
https://nuxt-security.vercel.app/documentation/middleware/allowed-methods-restricter.
